# IQKeyboardManager navigation from UITextField to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

`IQKeyboardManager` provides arrows in a toolbar just above my keyboard to jump from one `UITextField` to another but I am looking if I can jump between a mixture of `UITextFields` and `UITextViews`. I know the normal procedure to accomplish this task but I am interested to know if this is possible through `IQKeyboardManager`.

[Link to `IQKeyboardManager`](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you want to jump between textField and textView's. I think it's already implemented to jump a mixture of textField and textViews.

Comment: This might helps : https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: This is the screenshot of my simulator :
http://prntscr.com/5l1uh6
Please notice the next arrow disabled.
And This is my xib file:
http://prntscr.com/5l1us6
and you can clearly see that I have a textview next to the city textfield. 
If I firstly try to edit textview then arrow jumps work for other textfields but if I select any textfield first then arrow jump becomes disabled after city textfield.

Comment: Could UILabel next to the city textfield be a problem ? The top to bottom fields are usernameTextField,nametextField,dateOfBirthTextField,cityTextField,aboutMeLabel and then aboutMeTextView. Please let me know if this could be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have my textview below in layers to the textfield but at the bottom in the xib then this problem arises.
Check the following:

[image: this].

I drag-dropped the `UITextView` below textfields as follows: [image: this]

and it started working just fine.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: It helped me a lot, my whole confusion went. I was using nested views, and textfields inside them. So, IQKeyboardManager will not show next/previous buttons. And even Done button is not working properly in my case.