# IQkeyboardmanager issue with order

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using IQKeyBoardManager in my project, when the first text field is selected and next is pressed it skips my email text field and goes to the text field after email. How can I arrange the order in which the IQKeyBoardManager moves from text field to text field.
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648402/iqkeyboardmanager-navigation-from-uitextfield-to-uitextview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set hierarchy inside Document outline of storyboard in Xcode what ever hierarchy you want like below image:---

[image]